# Buscar dados com JSON

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, json

Preciso, através de um `<select> </select>`, trazer os dados para alguns `input[type='text']`. Acredito que seja através de JSON e AJAX, pois a página não pode ter nenhum "Submit".

**Por exemplo:**

Tenho um `<select> </select>` para selecionar um aluno da minha sala de aula, e alguns `input[type='text']` para trazer os dados do aluno selecionado, como "**idade**", "**número da sala**", "**nome da mãe**", "**nome do pai**", entre outros. A página não pode ter Submit pois eu tenho mais de um `<select> </select>` que fará o mesmo papel (ao selecionar um item, será exibido nos `input[type='text']` as características do mesmo). A forma que eu consegui desenvolver possibilita trazer os dados de um ou de outro `<select> </select>`.

Espero que tenham entendido meu problema. Sou inexperiente em JS.

Código em PHP:

```
<?php $query="SELECT idFunc AS 'ID', nomeFunc AS 'NOME', idadeFunc AS 'IDADE' FROM funcionario WHERE statusFunc = '1' ORDER BY nomeFunc"; ?>

<form method="GET" action="">
    <select name="aluno" onclick="if (this.value != ''){this.form.submit()};">
        <option value="">- ALUNOS -</option>

<?php   $sql =  odbc_exec($con, $query);

        $i=0; 
        while(odbc_fetch_row($sql)){

            $id=odbc_result($sql,"ID");
            $nome=odbc_result($sql,"NOME");
            $idade=odbc_result($sql,"IDADE");

            $i++;
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>" ><?php echo $nome; ?></option>
<?php   
        } odbc_close($con); 
?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Em PHP, eu consegui fazer o desejado, porém, quando eu seleciono outra caixa de seleção, ele apaga o primeiro resultado e exibe os resultados do segundo. Eu podia fazer o usuário selecionar os dois itens e depois de fazer um Submit, apareceria as informações, mas quero fazer um sistema mais intuitivo, em que o usuário apenas selecione e aparece em tempo real pra ele.

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sobre qualquer dúvida ou observação, estou a disposição.

Comment: o ideal é voce tentando fazer, assim a gente consegue ir te ajudando. Se já tiver algo feito, edita e posta o codigo.

Comment: Pode deixar, vou alterar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você já tem o web service no seu PHP?
Fazer uma solicitação assincronia (AJAX) com jQuery ou Axios é mais fácil, mas você também pode usar soluções nativas como o fetch.

```
function ajax(id) {
    return fetch(`/meuWebservice?id=${id}`).then(r => {
        if (r.ok) return r.json();
        throw r.text();
    });
}
```

Então no seu PHP você teria algo como

```
public function meuWebservice() {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM {/*sua tabela*/} WHERE idAluno = '$id'";
    $sql =  odbc_exec($con, $query);
    odbc_fetch_row($sql);

    $retorno = [];
    $retorno['resultado'] = [
        'idade' => $nome=odbc_result($sql,"IDADE"),
        'numero_da_sala' => $idade=odbc_result($sql,"NUMEROSALA"),
        'nome_mae' => $idade=odbc_result($sql,"NOMEMAE"),
        'nome_pai' => $idade=odbc_result($sql,"NOMEPAI")
    ];

    odbc_close($con);
    echo JSON_ENCODE($retorno);
    die();
}
```

Agora no JavaScript crie uma função para ser chamada no onchange do select. Também pode ser um eventListener. Declarar a função como async nos permite usar await para esperar a resposta do fetch, que é uma promise.

```
async function buscaInfo() {
    try{
        let {resultado} = await ajax(this.value);
        document.getElementById('idade_aluno').value = resultado.idade;
        document.getElementById('numero_sala').value = resultado.numero_sala;
        document.getElementById('nome_mae').value = resultado.nome_mae;
        document.getElementById('nome_pai').value = resultado.nome_pai;

    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Erro na consulta', await err);
    }   
}
```

Isso tudo é um exemplo meio cego, você vai precisar ajustar os ids dos elementos, arrumar a query do PHP, iniciar o $con com o valor correto.

Comment: Entendi. Eu agradeço muito pela ajuda. Mas quando eu selecionar o outro item, ele não vai zerar o primeiro Select e realizar o segundo?

Comment: Você não consegue tratar isso? Você pode mandar mais informações para o change, ou então acessar o this para saber de qual select se trata, e então mandar os valores para os inputs corretos.